# How to compute the limiting distribution of excess life, with uniform density?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm working on the reward/renewal process question and get stuck in the following question.

could anyone please lend me some help?

--
Question:

What is the limiting distribution of excess life,
when renewal lifetimes have the uniform density $f(x) = 1$, for $0<x<1$.

I know the answer is $h(x)=2(1-x)$,   but I don't know how this answer came up.

Comment: there is a type-o in the question above,   uniform density should be f(X)=1, for 0<x<1

Comment: Your question will likely get more attention if you define "excess life".

Comment: As in every renewal process, at stationarity, the excess life is distributed like $U\hat X$, where $U$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, $\hat X$ follows the size-biased distribution of the interarrival times, and $U$ and $\hat X$ are independent. If the interarrival times are uniform on $(0,1)$, the density of $\hat X$ is $2x$ on $(0,1)$ and the density of $U\hat X$ is $2(1-x)$ on $(0,1)$. Which textbook are you following?

Answer (score 2):

We know the mean $\mu$ for a uniform distribution is $\frac{1}{2}$. So utilizing what we know from Ross:

$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} P(\gamma_t \leq x) = \frac{1}{\mu} \int_0^x [1-F(t)] dt = 2x-x^2
$$

So the density is $2(1-x)$ for $0 < x <1$